# Linq search with several keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, search

I have searched a lot for some easy answer for this question, but I've failed. I'm totally new to MVC and have just created a little search-engine. It works excellent with 1 keyword, but not more than 1 keyword.

If i search for 'Ohio fishing' I want to get all users with those keywords from the database. How do I fix this in a few lines? Below is my current unmodified code:

```
    public ActionResult Search(string Users)
    {
        var v = from p in db.UserProfiles
                where (p.UserName.Contains(Users)) ||
                      (p.About.Contains(Users)) ||
                      (p.City.Contains(Users))
                select p;

        return View("Find", v.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: To clarify `Users` is actually a search term contain one or more words?

Comment: Yes, 'Users' contains the search keywords sent from the View.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not wrong, then I believe you want to search for the terms separately, i.e. for `'Ohio fishing'` you want to search for `Ohio` and fishing separately. In that case you need to split your string on white space and then use contains like:

```
public ActionResult Search(string Users)
{
    string[] terms = Users.Split();
    var v = from p in db.UserProfiles
            where (terms.Any(r=> p.UserName.Contains(r))) ||
                  (terms.Any(r => p.About.Contains(r))) ||
                  (terms.Any(r => p.City.Contains(r)))
            select p;

    return View("Find", v.ToList());
}
```

You should also look for [Full-Text search feature on SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: This changes the semantic, though, from "City contains {term}" to "City equals {term}, for one of the {terms}" (emphasis on the equals)

Comment: @MarcGravell, oh yes Marc, just going to change to Any with Contains.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried a few answers here and always get the same error:

LINQ To SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: Habib's answer worked when i added "AsEnumerable()"

... db.UserProfiles.AsEnumerable()

However, now it's case sensitive, hope I can fix this.

Thanks Habib.

Comment: @Varg, `AsEnumerable` would mean that you will get all the `UserProfiles` from database to program's memory and then you will do the processing their. Not really sure if you need this with a very large data set

Comment: @Varg, for case insensitive comparison you can use `.IndexOf(r,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0` instead of `Contains`

Comment: I understand the problem with AsEnumerable() in this case, however, since my database probably never will contains more than a handful lines, this is the solution for the moment. As my knowledge expands I'll upgrade some peaces later. By the way.. Thank you for the info about 'case sensitive', also that works as a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
public ActionResult Search(string[] Users)
{
    var v = from p in db.UserProfiles
            where (Users.Any(x=>p.UserName.Contains(x)) ||
                  (Users.Any(x=>p.About.Contains(x)) ||
                  (Users.Any(x=>p.City.Contains(x))
            select p;

    return View("Find", v.ToList());
}
```

Now how that works? take for instance the following:

```
Users.Any(x=>p.UserName.Contains(x))
```

This one checks if there is at least one item in the array called `Users`, where this item is contained int the current `UserName`. If so, then the result is true. Otherwise is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing to do is to use a [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build up a dynamic query.  This will work reasonably well for small queries across a relatively small database, but doesn't scale very well. A better solution would be to use a full-text search engine, like [Lucene.NET](http://lucenenet.apache.org/), to index your data and perform the search in a much more efficient manner.

```
public ActionResult Search(string[] Users)
{
    var terms = Users.Split();
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<User>90;
    foreach (var term in terms)
    {
         var temp = term; // avoid capture of loop variable
         predicate.Or(p => p.UserName.Contains(temp)
                            || p.About.Contains(temp)
                            || p.City.Contains(temp));
    }

    var v = db.UserProfiles.Where(predicate);

    return View("Find", v.ToList());
}
```